# Changing Couplings of Discrete Random Variables

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two discrete random variables. Two joint mass distributions (couplings) with marginals $X$ and $Y$ and with entries $p_{i,j}=\mathbb{P}_1(X=i,Y=j)$ and $p_{i,j}'=\mathbb{P}_2({X=i,Y=j})$  correspond to two matrices $(p_{i,j}), (p_{i,j}').$

Are there any techniques that provide a way to go from a given coupling of $X,Y$ to *any* other coupling of $X,Y$?
If so, can it be done using a linear transformation that maps $(p_{i,j})\mapsto(p_{i,j}')$?

The reason I ask is because I have a coupling of $X,Y$ and I wonder if a specific coupling exists. If there are any results that allow us to go from a 
 given coupling to any other coupling, perhaps this can be used to provide the desired coupling or show that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you mean by "switch"?

Comment: To obtain a new coupling of $X,Y$ from a given one. Will edit.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but another way to describe a coupling is by means of the stochastic matrix $P (X=i|Y=j) $ or vice versa.

Comment: @RonP, the entries in the joint mass distribution are $P(X=i, Y=j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j \vert X=i).$ Is this how the conditional probability describes the coupling, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant.